# Java / Jackson - 'Unrecognized token' passing JSON object parameter

Tags: java, json, post, deserialization

Java JAX-RS web service with Jersey / Jackson, a service method expects a User parameter (POJO) as JSON. The client app (Angular 6) sends a POST request containing the User parameter (serialized as JSON). The service method call fails with error message: "Unrecognized token 'jsonUser': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')".

Here is the User class (POJO) - you can see I tried annotating all the properties with @JsonProperty, but it's unnecessary, as I'm not "renaming" them:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

//import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

/**
 * JavaBean for passing the User properties between the UI app (Angular) 
 * and TearsWs. Implementation requires this to be serializable (JSON).
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "DELIM" })
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String userName;
    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private String homeUnitCode;
    private boolean certifier;
    private HomeUnit[] tkHomeUnits;
    private boolean supervisor;
    private Employee[] whoISupervise;
    private boolean hrStaff;
    private boolean collector;

    private final static String DELIM = ", ";

    public User() {
    }

    // getters / setters
    //@JsonProperty("userName")
    public void setUserName(String ldapUid) {
        this.userName = ldapUid;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("employeeId")
    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return this.employeeId;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("employeeName")
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return this.employeeName;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("homeUnitCode")
    public void setHomeUnitCode(String homeUnitCode) {
        this.homeUnitCode = homeUnitCode;
    }
    public String getHomeUnitCode() {
        return this.homeUnitCode;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("certifier")
    public void setCertifier(boolean certifier) {
        this.certifier = certifier;
    }
    public boolean getCertifier() {
        return this.certifier;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("tkHomeUnits")
    public void setTkHomeUnits(HomeUnit[] tkHomeUnitCodes) {
        this.tkHomeUnits = tkHomeUnitCodes;
    }
    public HomeUnit[] getTkHomeUnits() {
        return this.tkHomeUnits;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("supervisor")
    public void setSupervisor(boolean supervisor) {
        this.supervisor = supervisor;
    }
    public boolean isSupervisor() {
        return this.supervisor;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("whoISupervise")
    public void setWhoISupervise(Employee[] whoISupervise) {
        this.whoISupervise = whoISupervise;
    }
    public Employee[] getWhoISupervise() {
        return this.whoISupervise;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("hrStaff")
    public void setHrStaff(boolean hrStaff) {
        this.hrStaff = hrStaff;
    }
    public boolean isHrStaff() {
        return this.hrStaff;
    }

    //@JsonProperty("collector")
    public void setCollector(boolean collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }
    public boolean isCollector() {
        return this.collector;
    }

    //methods
    public boolean hasTauthority() {
        return this.certifier || this.collector;
    }

    public String toString() {
        int tkHUs = (tkHomeUnits == null) ? 0 : tkHomeUnits.length;
        return "[User: "
            + "userName=" + this.userName + DELIM 
            + "employeeId=" + this.employeeId + DELIM 
            + "employeeName=" + this.employeeName + DELIM 
            + "homeUnitCode=" + this.homeUnitCode + DELIM
            + "certifier=" + this.certifier + DELIM 
            + "hrStaff=" + this.hrStaff + DELIM 
            + "collector=" + this.collector + DELIM
            + "I can certify " + tkHUs + " homeUnits" + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is the (Java) service method, which should accept and process the POST request:

```
/**
 * Web service method.
 */
@POST
@Path("getTkHomeUnitEmployees")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTkHomeUnitEmployees(User user, @HeaderParam("X-Request-Param") String homeUnitCode) throws Exception {
    String exceptionMessage;

    if (user == null) {
        exceptionMessage = "getTkHomeUnitEmployees() received a null User.";
        log.error(exceptionMessage);
        Response response = Response
                .status(500)
                .entity(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
        return response;
    }
    if (homeUnitCode == null || homeUnitCode.equals("")) {
        exceptionMessage = "getTkHomeUnitEmployees() received a null HomeUnitCode.";
        log.error(exceptionMessage);
        Response response = Response
                .status(500)
                .entity(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
        return response;
    }
    if (!user.hasTauthority()) {
        exceptionMessage = "getTkHomeUnitEmployees() received a request from a non-timekeeper and non-collector.";

        log.error(exceptionMessage);
        Response response = Response
                .status(500)
                .entity(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
        return response;
    }
    try {
        Employee[] tkHomeUnitEmployees = new SecurityDao().getTkHomeUnitEmployees(user.getEmployeeId(), homeUnitCode);

        Response response = Response
                .ok(tkHomeUnitEmployees)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        exceptionMessage = "getTkHomeUnitEmployees(): " + ex;
        Response response = Response
                .status(500)
                .entity(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

The User object (client side, Javascript) is converted to JSON and encapsulated as a parameter in HttpParams; the POST passes it in the body of the request.

Here is the (Angular) client method, which sends the POST request to the web service:

```
getTkHomeUnitEmployees(user: User, homeUnitCode: string): Observable<Employee[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('X-Request-Param', homeUnitCode); // homeUnitCode parameter in HttpHeaders

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: headers
    };

    let jsonUser: string = JSON.stringify(user);

    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
        .set('jsonUser', jsonUser);

    let postUrl = this.wsUrl + 'getTkHomeUnitEmployees';
    //postUrl += '?homeUnitCode=' + homeUnitCode; // homeUnitCode parameter as QueryParam

    let obsArrayEmployees: Observable<Employee[]> = this.httpClient.post<Employee[]>(postUrl, httpParams, httpOptions);
    return obsArrayEmployees;
}
```

...here I'm debugging the client (@ browser Dev Tools), with a break in the getTkHomeUnitEmployees() method:

[image: debug getTkHomeUnitEmployees]

...I've displayed the value of jsonUser in the Console:

[image: debug - jsonUser value]

...here is the error in the Response:

[image: error - Response 400]

[image: error - Response Unrecognized token]

...and here is the Request Params.

[image: error - Request payload]

So, it appears the Jackson JsonParser is attempting to read and parse the parameter sent in the request, but the parameter includes "jsonUser=" at the beginning as part of it's value (json to be parsed).  This is clearly wrong...

The service method blows up before actually entering / processing code; I can't set a breakpoint within the service method to examine the value of the parameter.  It behaves as a "parameter invalid, return to caller" response.

I thought to manually hack the "jsonUser=" out of it (@ client side), but it's not there. At the client, "jsonUser=" is not part of the parameter value; I believe it's just the key=value syntax of an http parameter (parameter-name=parameter-value), perhaps it's being prepended when the parameter is encapsulated into the HttpParams object.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to figure it out; I thought this was the correct way to do this, but apparently not. Hope someone can help soon, I've been stuck on this for a couple days already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to covert the 'user' object to string to pass to backend. Try passing the user object as it is.

```
this.httpClient.post<Employee[]>(postUrl, user, httpOptions);
```

And also please check if parameters passed really match the rest service exposed.

Comment: OMG, that was it...! I figured it was something simple, thanks for your help!